# Android inject event permission doesn't work

Tags: android, root

I have `android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS` in `Manifest.xml` but I can't use `TouchEventExec()`.

I think I can do it with a root command, but I don't know a root command for `TouchEventExec()`

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary SDK applications cannot hold the `INJECT_EVENTS` permission, for obvious security reasons. Your app would have to be signed with the same signing key as signed the firmware, which is only practical if you are creating your own firmware.